# functionTimeout in hosts.json not recognized by function app host runtime version ~3

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

With below mentioned host.json, we see that function timeout is set to default of 30 mins. Some of our workflows run beyond 30 mins. This was working in runtime ~2. Also by checking the logs from host startup, there is no way to see the timeout value picked by the runtime. Is it logged ?

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
"logging": {
"logLevel": {
"Default": "Debug"
}
}
}
```

Comment: could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 3):

The `host.json` is correct, the version is just for the schema.

I just had a similar issue, and it turns out registering `IConfiguration` as a singleton re-instates the default values.

So do not do this in `Startup.cs`:

`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);`

Comment: how did you figure this out?

Comment: Trial and error, anything particular?

Comment: just looking if i missed any doc